# Why cant i pass more then 1 variable to another function?

Tags: python, flask

I am getting TypeError: get_entity_id() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

i am getting user input from a ajax form,

```
getFormData = (request.form)
reportName = (getFormData['reportName'])
districtName = (getFormData['districtName'])
rapid7Query = (getFormData['rapid7Query'])
rapid7SeverityLevel = (getFormData['rapid7SeverityLevel'])
```

Id like to be able to pass these to another python function

```
print("In post request response...")

response = insightvmreport.check_action(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel)
```

when i do this, im getting an error,

```
TypeError: get_entity_id() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I have the other function, accept the arguments... (in insightvmreport.py file, this is the check_action() function:

```
def check_action(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel):

    print(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel)
    action = "download"
    if action == "download":

        scan_id,site_id = get_entity_id(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel)

        if scan_id and site_id:

            response = configure_report(scan_id,site_id)

            return response
```

error:

```
test District 1 (EUR) SELECT * FROM dim_asset ORDER BY ip_address ASC Medium
[2022-09-21 11:48:05,216] ERROR in app: Exception on /rapid7/submit_report/process [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/bin/auth_functions.py", line 52, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/views/rapid7/view.py", line 44, in process
    response = insightvmreport.check_action(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/services/rapid7/insightvmreport.py", line 19, in check_action
    scan_id,site_id = get_entity_id(reportName, districtName, rapid7Query, rapid7SeverityLevel)
TypeError: get_entity_id() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: you just can't give it more arguments than it accepts, what's not clear about that?

Comment: The error message says the problem is in `get_entity_id()`...

Comment: The function `get_entity_id()` only has two arguments. You either supply it the two arguments it needs or you rewrite that function to accept four arguments (and then do something with them).

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to try ```scan_id, site_id = get_entity_id(reportName, rapid7Query), get_entity_id(districtName, rapid7SeverityLevel)``` or better yet split them up into two different lines

Comment: Start by looking at the definition and/or documentation for `get_entity_id` to learn how it should be called.

Comment: i have all four, why do i need to split them up?

Comment: Are you trying to extract two ids?

Comment: the extraction happens farther down, im just trying to get user input to put in to a parameters function

Answer (score 0):

#### The function `get_entity_id` only takes two arguments.  It has no idea what to do with more than two.

From your code it looks like you're trying to extract two entity ids, so you might need to split those two calls into two lines.

```
scan_id = get_entity_id(reportName, rapid7Query)
site_id = get_entity_id(districtName, rapid7SeverityLevel)
```

In order to use it twice (which I am assuming is your goal) you'll have to call it twice.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i think im understanding it more, howeeer i dont want to run the code twice, just want to pass those variables in, maybee i should create another function instead of using the existing one

Comment: To be clear, you only need to call ```get_entity_id``` twice, not the whole program.  Running a simple function twice won't have an impact on your run time.  I'd strongly suggest you run it twice rather than make a new function.